# Laravel how to put related columns with the same date in an array

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I am at the moment calling a few nested relations. But what I am trying to do is to get all the columns with the same "measured_at" date in one array instead of them being spread.

A brief example of the structure that I am getting:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_body_sizes": [
        {
            "id": 23,
            "measured_at": "2023-04-04"
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "measured_at": "2023-04-04"
        },
        {
            "id": 26,
            "measured_at": "2023-03-14"
        },
        {
            "id": 29,
            "measured_at": "2023-03-14"
        }
    ]
}
```

So this is what I actually want to achieve:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "user_body_sizes": [
        [
            {
                "id": 23,
                "measured_at": "2023-04-04"
            },
            {
                "id": 24,
                "measured_at": "2023-04-04"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "id": 29,
                "measured_at": "2023-03-14"
            },
            {
                "id": 26,
                "measured_at": "2023-03-14"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

So basically I want the data with the same "measured_at" date to be in the same array.

So in Laravel this is my code at the moment to get the data:

```
public function GetCustomerBodySize($customerId, $month, $year)
    {
        $customerUserId = Customer::findOrFail($customerId)['user'];

        return CustomerBodySize::with([ 'customer_data.user_body_sizes.body_parts','customer_data.user_body_sizes' => function ($q) use ($month, $year){
            $q->whereMonth('measured_at', '=', $month);
            $q->whereYear('measured_at', '=', $year);
            $q->orderBy('measured_at');
        }])
            ->whereRelation('customer_data', 'id', $customerUserId)
            ->first();
    }
```

And here are my relations:

```
// This is in my CustomerBodySize model
function customer_data(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'customer');
    }

function body_parts(){
        return $this->belongsTo(BodyParts::class, 'body_part');
    }

// This is in my User model
public function user_body_sizes(){
        return $this->hasMany(CustomerBodySize::class, 'customer');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Laravel's` Collection's `groupBy()` method to group the `user_body_sizes` by their `measured_at` date

1. we are first `fetching all` the relevant `CustomerBodySize` records with the given filters using `get()` instead of `first()`
2. And then we make group `user_body_sizes`  by their `measured_at` date using the `groupBy()` method
3. At last, we use `map()` to return an array of arrays, with each `nested` array containing the `CustomerBodySize` records that share the same `measured_at date`. We also use `values()` to remove the `grouping keys` from the `resulting collection`.
4. If there are no records matching the given filters, we return `null` .

#### Modified Code is Here

```
public function GetCustomerBodySize($customerId, $month, $year)

{

$customerUserId = Customer::findOrFail($customerId)['user'];

$bodySizes = CustomerBodySize::with([
    'customer_data.user_body_sizes.body_parts',
    'customer_data.user_body_sizes' => function ($q) use ($month, $year) {
        $q->whereMonth('measured_at', '=', $month);
        $q->whereYear('measured_at', '=', $year);
        $q->orderBy('measured_at');
    }
])
->whereRelation('customer_data', 'id', $customerUserId)
->get();

$groupedBodySizes = $bodySizes->groupBy(function ($item) {
    return $item->measured_at;
});

$result = $groupedBodySizes->map(function ($item) {
    return $item->values();
})->values();

return $result->isEmpty() ? null : $result->first();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function GetCustomerBodySize($customerId, $month, $year)
    {
        $customerUserId = Customer::findOrFail($customerId)['user'];

        $data = CustomerBodySize::with([ 'customer_data.user_body_sizes.body_parts','customer_data.user_body_sizes' => function ($q) use ($month, $year){
            $q->whereMonth('measured_at', '=', $month);
            $q->whereYear('measured_at', '=', $year);
            $q->orderBy('measured_at');
        }])
            ->whereRelation('customer_data', 'id', $customerUserId)
            ->first();

        // this did the job for me
        $data = $data->toArray();

        $groupedUserBodySizes = collect($data['customer_data']['user_body_sizes'])->groupBy('measured_at')->values()->toArray();

        $data['customer_data']['user_body_sizes'] = $groupedUserBodySizes;

        return $data;
    }
```